# How to come back to same if statement if the condition fails in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

Is it possible to hold the script at a "if statement" unless condition mentioned fulfiled ?

```
echo "enter the ID"  <----------------Point A 

read var 

if [ "$var" == "55" ];then  <------------Point B 
echo "good" 

fi
```

Desired output is:

If condition in point B fails then again show point A asking for inputs. Stop the flow of script unless correct input is provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `while` condition with a `break` can make it:

```
while true;
do
        echo "enter the ID"
        read var 

        if [ "$var" = "55" ];then
           echo "good" 
           break
        fi 
done
```